# How to filter file in Telerik MVC Upload?

Tags: upload, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik Upload in my MVC3 Project. I need to make the select file window as only showing the Text files rather than showing all the file types files. Is there any way that i can make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik Forum has an answer for this. See [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/upload/is-it-possible-to-restrict-allowed-file-types.aspx#1915324) from the Telerik Team.

Comment: But Firefox is not filtering file types. Is there any other way?

Comment: dead link!  please answer with SO in the future

Answer (score 2):

The following code filter only ***jpeg/jpg*** and ***png*** file. Also check when select a file whether it is a ***valid extension*** file.

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Upload()
            .Name("attachments")
            .Multiple(false)
            .Async(async => async
            .Save("AddImg", "Home")
            .AutoUpload(false)
            )
            .ClientEvents(events => events
            .OnLoad("onLoad")
            .OnSelect("onSelect")
            .OnSuccess("onSuccess")
            )
        )

<script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoad(e) {
        $(this).find("input").attr("accept", "image\/jpeg,image\/jpg,image\/png");
    }

    function onSelect(e) {

        if (e.files[0].size > 102400) {
            alert('The file size is too large for upload');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } 

        var ext = e.files[0].extension.toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(ext, ['.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png']) == -1) {
            alert('This type of file is restricted from being uploaded due to security reasons');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```